# How to use jquery to set td background-color red when evey row's first input is null or last input is null?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table like this:
[image]

Every row's second td and fourth td and sixth td has a input text in it.

I want to check every row's input text in second td and sixth td.

The second td and sixth td must input,the fourth td can be null.

If the second td's input is null or sixth td's input is null.Then set the input cell background-color to red.Just like my picture.

Here is my html [code](https://jsfiddle.net/2q6rg5pk/12/),I know jquery $.each may do it,but how to do?

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a validation it would be much simpler if you tagged the rows which will be validated (second and six).

What you could do is, add a `class` to the required fields and then only use that to validate the input fields.

```js
$('.required input').on('blur', function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $(this).parents('td').css('background', 'red');
  } else {
    $(this).parents('td').css('background', 'transparent');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>111</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="inner_div_reach_condition_appoint" class="panel-body">
      <table id="table_reach_condition_appoint" border="1" class="table table-bordered text-right">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-thead-tr">
            <th class="text-center">No</th>
            <th colspan="4" class="text-center">AA</th>

            <th class="text-center">BB</th>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
            <th style="display:none;"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody_reach_condition_appoint">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>before</span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>go</span>
            </td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>before</span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>go</span>
            </td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>before</span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>go</span>
            </td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>before</span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>go</span>
            </td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>before</span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-center disabledItemBgColor">
              <span>go</span>
            </td>
            <td class="required">
              <input type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">✖</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This way the validation happens as you go through the inputs which need validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:nth-child` CSS selector

```js
$("table tbody tr").each(function(){

  let secChild = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) input');
  let sixChild = $(this).find('td:nth-child(6) input');
  
  if( secChild.val() == "" ){
    secChild.css('background-color' ,'red');
  }
  
  if( sixChild.val() == "" ){
    sixChild.css('background-color' ,'red');
  }

});
```

```css
table, input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>

    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
       </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

please provide the markup of what 'null' would be to you, so we can help you with a better answer.

Assuming is as simple as '', something in the lines of

```
$("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr").each(function(){
  $(this).children('td').each(function(){
    if ( !$(this).text().length ){$(this).css( "color", "red" );}
  });
});
```

could do the trick.
best regards

Comment: `.length` on td will give you if it exists or not and will not check the input inside the td

Comment: @SimranjitSingh Is right. You need `$(this).text().length`

Comment: actually using the your snippet it would require $(this).find('input').val()